# Collapsible Section R Markdown with Code in lists

Tags: r, list, markdown

I would like to have a collapsible section with code in my R Markdown file in the following way:

```
- Text Text Text
- Text Text Text
<details>
   <summary>See code</summary>
''' {r, echo=TRUE}
code code code
'''
</details>

<details>
   <summary>See plot</summary>
''' {r, echo=FALSE}
ggplot code
'''
</details>
```

The ggplot is shown in a collapsible way, but the code isn't hided and by clicking on "See Code" nothing happens (collapsed are is empty).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is relatively easy:

```
<details>
   <summary>See code</summary>
     ''' {r, echo=TRUE}
     code code code
     '''
</details>
<details>
   <summary>See plot</summary>
     ''' {r, echo=FALSE}
     ggplot code
     '''
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your please share a little more information, like your YAML header? And have you tried to include

```
output:
   html_document:
       code_folding: hide
```

*sorry, I would have had written this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation to do so...

Comment: Yes. I worked with code_folding before, but I don't like it. This is why I want to work the way I described above. And normally, it works. But in the case I described (with a list) the folded area is empty